# Show $\lim_{X \to -k}\:\prod_{j\neq k}\left(X+j \right)=(-1)^{k}k!\left(n-k \right).)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, integer-partitions

> I would like to know how to show that :
>   $$\lim_{X \to -k}\:\prod_{j\neq k}\left(X+j \right)=(-1)^{k}k!\left(n-k \right).$$

This is came from solution of exercise that he said :

- what is Partial fraction decomposition of :

$$F(X)=\dfrac{n!}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(X+k \right)}$$

indeed,

PFD of F:

$$F(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{a_k}{X+k} $$

$$\left(X+k\right)F(X)=\dfrac{n!}{\prod_{j\neq k}\left(X+j \right)}$$
and 
$$\prod_{j\neq k}\left(X+j \right)=(-1)^{k}k!\left(n-k \right)$$ then :

$$a_k=(-1)^{k}{n \choose k} $$

Finaly:

$$F(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}{n \choose k}\dfrac{1}{X+k} $$

Comment: There's no $X$ on the right hand side of your equality. It's strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would rather like to prove

> $$
> \lim_{X \to -k}\:\prod_{j\neq k}\left(X+j \right)=(-1)^{k}k!\left(n-k \right).
> $$

If this is the case, one may observe that 
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{X \to -k}\:\prod_{j\neq k}\left(X+j \right)&=\left.\prod_{j\neq k}\left(X+j \right)\right|_{X=-k}
\\\\&=\prod_{j\neq k}\left(-k+j \right)
\\\\&=\prod_{0\le j \le k,\,j\neq k}\left(-k+j \right)\prod_{k\le j \le n,\,j\neq k}\left(-k+j \right)
\\\\&=(-1)^{k}\prod_{0\le j \le k-1}\left(k-j \right)\prod_{k+1\le j \le n}\left(j-k \right)
\\\\&=(-1)^kk!(n-k)!
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mrm{F}\pars{X}} & =
{n! \over \prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{X + k}} =
{n! \over \prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{k + X}} =
{n! \over \pars{X}_{n + 1}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\pars{a}_{m}}$ is the *Pochhammer Symbol*.

---

Also,
\begin{align}
\prod_{j \not= k}\pars{X + j} & = {n! \over \pars{X + k}\,\mrm{F}\pars{X}} =
{n! \over \pars{X + k}\bracks{n!/\pars{X}_{n + 1}}} =
{\pars{X}_{n + 1} \over X + k} =
{\Gamma\pars{X + n + 1} \over \pars{X + k}\Gamma\pars{X}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{X + n}! \over \pars{X + k}\pars{X - 1}!} =
{\pars{X + n}\ldots X \over X + k} =
\pars{X + n}\ldots\pars{X + k + 1}\pars{X + k - 1}\ldots X
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\lim_{X \to -k}\,\,\,\prod_{j \not= k}\pars{X + j} & =
\pars{-k + n}\pars{-k + n - 1}\ldots 1\bracks{\pars{-1}\ldots\pars{-k}}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{n - k}!\bracks{\pars{-1}^{k}\,1 \times 2 \ldots k} =
\color{#f00}{\pars{-1}^{k}\,k!\pars{n - k}!}
\end{align}